# Laravel Polymorphic Relation store data at same time

Tags: php, database, laravel, polymorphism

I have morph relation between posts pages and tags table.

```
Posts
    id
    othercolumn

Pages
    id
    othercolumn

tags
    id
    othercolumn
    tagable_id
    tagable_type
```

Example: i want add post to posts table and tag to tags table at same time

```
DB::transaction(function(){
        $post = new Post;
        $post->othercolumn = Input::get('something');

        $tags = new Tag;
        $tag->othercolumn = Input::get('something');


        // here function to store post and tag


        if( //post or tag not created )
        {
            throw new \Exception('Failed to create post or tag');
        }
    });
```

if i use function save morph relation like $post->tagable()->save($tag). will show error tagable_id cannot be null.

Comment: you can`t do this, because you need post id

Comment: so how can i get post id? if try get post id using $post->id but return null... because using db transaction... its still posible to make that method?

Comment: create post in first, in second create tag

Comment: if create post first and tags second.... how can i delete post when tag not created... like db transaction... will rollback post

Comment: if (!$tags->save()) {$post->delete();}

Comment: ok now its work thank for your time...

Comment: @J.Doe you should write an answer, and OP should accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can`t store to models in same time, but you can delete first model if second not saved:

```
DB::transaction(function(){
    $post = new Post;
    $post->othercolumn = Input::get('something');

    $tag = new Tag;
    $tag->othercolumn = Input::get('something');


    if(!$post->save() || !$tag->save())
    {
        throw new \Exception('Failed to create post or tag');
    }
});
```